# How to overline letters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Anyone have any idea how to `Overline` letters in `SSRS`, or maybe any other workarounds to achieve this?

Original source  how to overline text is [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/226757/how-to-overline-text-in-word/)

Thank you all.

Comment: Sorry that formatting fom text box properties doesn't work. Any other walk arounds ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out after questioning.
In the Text box properties>>>Format>>>Overline.